# Custom action or command in C using libfm Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, gtk, glib

I'm working in a custom action for pcmanfm, I'm editing the file "main-win.c", here the code:

```
static void on_open(GtkAction* act, FmMainWin* win) {
    FmFileInfoList *files = fm_folder_view_dup_selected_files(win->folder_view);
    if (files) {
        GList* l = fm_file_info_list_peek_head_link(files);
        if (g_list_length(l) > 0)
            fm_launch_files_simple(GTK_WINDOW(win), NULL, l, pcmanfm_open_folder, NULL);
        fm_file_info_list_unref(files);
    }
}
```

**"FmFileInfoList *files"** Is the list of the SELECTED FILES in the file manager window.

**"GList* l"** Is the conversion of a list into a Doubly-Linked Lists.

the function **fm_launch_files_simple()** runs all files in the linked list with the default program, like "gedit /home/someuser/some.txt" or "totem /home/someuser/video.mp4".

Who I need?, I need to execute a custom command or function in all SELECTED FILES using a loop, which is the command? this is the command:

```
fm_launch_command_simple(GTK_WINDOW(win), NULL, 0, "somecommand", NULL);
```

**fm_launch_command_simple()**, is a libfm function who runs a bash command in the console where pcmanfm are executed...

Here a example of who I want to do, using the "**printf**" function:

```
static void on_open(GtkAction* act, FmMainWin* win) {
    FmFileInfoList *files = fm_folder_view_dup_selected_files(win->folder_view);
    if (files) {
        //GList* l = fm_file_info_list_peek_head_link(files);
        //if (g_list_length(l) > 0)
            //fm_launch_files_simple(GTK_WINDOW(win), NULL, l, pcmanfm_open_folder, NULL);
        for (file in files) {
            printf("echo File selected: " + file[i]);
        }
        fm_file_info_list_unref(files);
    }
}
```

Here other example using the function "**fm_launch_command_simple**":

```
static void on_open(GtkAction* act, FmMainWin* win) {
    FmFileInfoList *files = fm_folder_view_dup_selected_files(win->folder_view);
    if (files) {
        //GList* l = fm_file_info_list_peek_head_link(files);
        //if (g_list_length(l) > 0)
            //fm_launch_files_simple(GTK_WINDOW(win), NULL, l, pcmanfm_open_folder, NULL);
        for (file in files) {
            fm_launch_command_simple(GTK_WINDOW(win), NULL, 0, "echo File selected: " + file[i], NULL);
        }
        fm_file_info_list_unref(files);
    }
}
```

I'm new in this programing language.

Answer (score 0):

Use g_list_foreach https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#g-list-foreach

You then create a function of void (*GFunc) (gpointer listItem, gpointer otherStuffEnteredInGListForeach) that wraps fm_launch_command_simple.